# XAMPP codeigniter Database Error

Tags: php, database, codeigniter, xampp

I face an error when trying the tutorial of CodeIgniter. When I try the "News section". I get the error

A Database Error Occurred

Unable to connect to your database server using the provided settings.

Filename: C:\xampp\htdocs\CI\system\database\DB_driver.php

Line Number: 124

I am using XAMPP and my os is windows7(64 bit).

My details in the C:\xampp\htdocs\CI\application\config\database.php are follows

```
$db['default']['hostname'] = 'localhost';
$db['default']['username'] = 'root';
$db['default']['password'] = '';
$db['default']['database'] = 'xxx';
$db['default']['dbdriver'] = 'mysql';
$db['default']['dbprefix'] = '';
$db['default']['pconnect'] = TRUE;
$db['default']['db_debug'] = TRUE;
$db['default']['cache_on'] = FALSE;
$db['default']['cachedir'] = '';
$db['default']['char_set'] = 'utf8';
$db['default']['dbcollat'] = 'utf8_general_ci';
$db['default']['swap_pre'] = '';
$db['default']['autoinit'] = TRUE;
$db['default']['stricton'] = FALSE;
```

I succeeded When to establish the connection to db with core php.

Somebody help me to resolve this..
Thanks in advance..

Comment: Are you sure that xxx database exist? Also try replacing dbdriver from mysql with mysqli

Comment: Did you load Database class before using it ?

Answer (score 0):

Reset XAMPP and check if phpmyadmin working and database 'xxx' exist.

Answer (score 0):

using phpmyadmin create the database..name it xxx
then try loading the site again

Also check the index.php file in the root folder. 
Sometimes people will place code here to change which database file it uses based on the domain.. not sure what codeigniter tutorial you are following.

Comment: i use the default turorials the link is http://ellislab.com/codeigniter%20/user-guide/tutorial/news_section.html

Comment: @Jerin So did you create the database using phpmyadmin or adminer.. something like this. And did you name it xxx. This is just a basic tutorial.. right now the tutorial is irrelevant until you can establish a connection with your database. Go to http://localhost/phpmyadmin and check that out

Answer (score 0):

first make sure you load your database library

```
$autoload['libraries'] = array('database');
```

then check your default settings to see whether something is missing using.

```
   echo '<pre>';
   print_r($db['default']);
   echo '</pre>';
```

Answer (score 0):

Set db_debug to false in your CI's database.php.

Another tip. When locally everything is very very slow, change localhost to 127.0.0.1.

Answer (score 0):

Kamikaze™ - 08 December 2011 06:39 AM
Is your table name in uppercase? Be careful with lowercase and uppercase, I had the same problem.
Try this: `$this->db->get(“PROJECT_USERS”);`